# unity 5 co routine wont exit when told to

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am making a game where the player battles a robot, I have implemented some code to make the AI move back and rotate away from the player if a condition is met. However the co routine that does this loops forever and I am unsure in how to make it break.

```
void Update () 
    {
        //looking at player
        playerVelocity = ((TTarget.position - previous).magnitude) / Time.deltaTime;
        previous = TTarget.position;

        GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.Find("Player");
        PlayerMovement playerMovement = thePlayer.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        enemyHit = playerMovement.hitEnemy;

        if (enemyHit == false)
        {
            //enemy moving
            transform.LookAt(TTarget);
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
        }
        else if (enemyHit == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine("Evade");
            //Debug.Log ("Hello");
            StopCoroutine("Evade");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Evade()
    {
        //GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.Find("Player");
        //PlayerMovement playerMovement = thePlayer.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        //enemyHit = playerMovement.hitEnemy;

        transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        Vector3 to = new Vector3(0, -45, 0);
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.eulerAngles, to) > 0.01f)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.rotation.eulerAngles, to, 99*Time.deltaTime);
        }

        yield break;


    }
```

Comment: I see you have a `Debug.Log()` in between the coroutines, when you uncomment that, do you see it being printed to the log?

Comment: Please note that if an answer provided by a user satisfactorily answers your question, then you should accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. Ensure you review this and any previous questions you have asked, to determine whether any given answers can be accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are starting the coroutine, then immediately stopping it.

```
void Update () 
{
    enemyHit = playerMovement.hitEnemy;

    if (enemyHit == false)
    {
        //enemy moving
        transform.LookAt(TTarget);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
    }
    else if (enemyHit == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine("Evade");
        Debug.Log ("Back From Coroutine");
        StopCoroutine("Evade");
        Debug.Log("Stopped Coroutine");
    }
}

IEnumerator Evade()
{
    Debug.Log("Starting Coroutine");
    transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    Debug.Log("This is never called");

    Vector3 to = new Vector3(0, -45, 0);
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.eulerAngles, to) > 0.01f)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.rotation.eulerAngles, to, 99*Time.deltaTime);
    }
    yield break;
}
```

This would output:

```
Starting Coroutine
Back From Coroutine
Stopped Coroutine
```

I think the better would to do this would just be with a bool and `Invoke` http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html

```
private bool avoidPlayer = false;
void Update () 
{
    enemyHit = playerMovement.hitEnemy;

    if (enemyHit == false)
    {
        //enemy moving
        transform.LookAt(TTarget);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
    }
    else if (enemyHit == true)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
        avoidPlayer = true;
    }
    // Invoke the evade function every second until we have avoided the player
    if(avoidPlayer)
        Invoke("Evade", 1);
}

void Evade()
{
    Vector3 to = new Vector3(0, -45, 0);
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.eulerAngles, to) > 0.01f)
        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(
                                    transform.rotation.eulerAngles, to, 99*Time.deltaTime);
    else
        avoidPlayer = false;
}
```